# Cannot redirect Traefik dashboard to https and set up password

Tags: traefik

I want the traefik dashboard to only connect via https but at the same time provide authentication. I also want traefik to automatically redirect to https if I access the http address.

I've tried configuring myself by adding traefik dashboard http redirection to https and adding htpasswd authentication. But sadly it doesn't work.

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https", "traefik", "traefik-https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.traefik]
  address = ":8080"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.traefik.redirect]
    entryPoint = "traefik-https"
    [entryPoints.traefik-https.tls]
      [entryPoints.traefik-https.auth]
        [entryPoints.traefik-https.auth.basic]
        users = [
          "test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/",
        ]
    sniStrict = true
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    ]
      [entryPoints.traefik-https.tls.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
      keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
        [[entryPoints.traefik-https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
        keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
    sniStrict = true
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    ]
      [entryPoints.https.tls.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
      keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
        [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
        keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[file]

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host: example.com,www.example.com"
  [frontends.frontend2]
  backend = "backend2"
    [frontends.frontend2.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host: duplicati.example.com,www.duplicati.example.com"
  [frontends.frontend3]
  entryPoints = ["traefik"]
  backend = "backend3"
    [frontends.frontend3.routes.test_1]
      rule = "Host: traefik.example.com"

  [backends]
    [backends.backend1]
      [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:56000"
      weight = 1
    [backends.backend2]
      [backends.backend2.servers.server1]
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:57000"
      weight = 1
    [backends.backend3]
      [backends.backend3.servers.server1]
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
      weight = 1
```

I expected it to redirect to https automatically when I access `http://example.com:8080`. Like this `http://example.com:8080` --> `https://example.com:8080`. But when I access `https://example.com:8080` it gave me an error `Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successfully fixed the problem. I don't know how I did it but I started from zero, refered to the Traefik docs, test my code, try, try, and try again until my code works!

Here is the code just in case someone needs it as a future reference

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https", "traefik", "traefik-https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.foo]
  address=":58080"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.foo.redirect]
    entrypoint="traefik-https"
  [entryPoints.traefik-https]
  address = ":58443"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.traefik-https.tls]
    sniStrict = true
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    ]
      [entryPoints.traefik-https.tls.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
      keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
        [[entryPoints.traefik-https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
        keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
          [entryPoints.traefik-https.auth]
            [entryPoints.traefik-https.auth.basic]
            users = [
              "test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/",
              "test2:$apr1$d9hr9HBB$4HxwgUir3HP4EsggP/QNo0",
            ]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
    sniStrict = true
    minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
    cipherSuites = [
      "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256",
      "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
      "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
      "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    ]
      [entryPoints.https.tls.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
      keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"
        [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem"
        keyFile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem"

[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik-https"
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[file]

[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host: example.com,www.example.com"
  [frontends.frontend2]
  backend = "backend2"
    [frontends.frontend2.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host: duplicati.example.com,www.duplicati.example.com"
#  [frontends.frontend3]
#  entryPoints = ["traefik"]
#  backend = "backend3"
#    [frontends.frontend3.routes.test_1]
#      rule = "Host: traefik.example.com"

  [backends]
    [backends.backend1]
      [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:56000"
      weight = 1
    [backends.backend2]
      [backends.backend2.servers.server1]
      url = "http://127.0.0.1:57000"
      weight = 1
#    [backends.backend3]
#      [backends.backend3.servers.server1]
#      url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
#      weight = 1
```

Traefik docs that I've refered to:

- https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/web/
- https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/